# swagger 2.0 errors on body parameters

Tags: swagger-2.0

I have two errors

Next to `- name: data`

```
Schema error at paths['/datas/{id}'].patch.parameters[1]
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: descripton, schema, name, in, required
```

Next to `- in: body`

```
Schema error at paths['/datas/{id}'].patch.parameters[1].in
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: header, formData, query, path
```

I've error only for patch methods and body parameters

swaggger.yml

```
swagger: '2.0'
patch:
  summary: Update one data
  description: |
    Update a data
  tags:
    - datas
  parameters:
    - name: id
      in: path
      description: ID of the data to update
      required: true
      type: integer
    - name: data
      in: body
      descripton: name of the data
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/patchData'
  responses:
    '204':
      description: Update successful
```

I've check specs here
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/

Comment: Body param description contains a typo: `descripton` -> `descsription`.

Comment: thanks ! I needed a new eye !